# How do B+ Tree text (username, email) indexes work

Tags: database-design, index, btree

From my understanding, MongoDB uses a B+ Tree for indexes, including for unique fields such as emails and usernames.

However, I don't understand how a string value such as an email or username gets converted to a numeric format (that can be sorted with ascending, descending).

Can anyone help me understand? Are the string values getting converted to numbers? How is a B+ Tree done per character?

Any examples or resources to read on would be great. (I am trying to implement some kind of B+ Tree that can support indexing of usernames

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: Why do you think the string has to be converted to an integer? That's the text book example for sure, but B Trees work just fine with strings.

Comment: @MichaelGreen how do you know if a string is larger or smaller than another?

Comment: Larger in number of characters or in dictionary order? Counting characters works the same way it does in other software. Dictionary order can be by ASCII code for very simple cases or by [collation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_collation_algorithm) for unicode. Every major DBMS will support unicode.

Comment: A BTree is an ordered list of index key values, with some additional things added on. If the DBMS supports ORDER BY on string columns it can support a BTree on string columns, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back to answer my own question:

Apparently, you can just compare strings using greater than & less than operators, which I was unaware of.

For example, in JavaScript:

[image]